# Apache - Rewrite the subdomain to a location?

Tags: php, apache, redirect, subdomain

I am sorry, I have tried for hours to get this working, but I haven't made progress...

I want to make it so that if a user on my site types `user.site.com` they will be taken to `site.com/user`, but the URL will still show `user.site.com`. How can I do this? With .htaccess? Server files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there Ken

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-_]+).site.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %1/$1 [QSA,L]
```

%1 = what's before .site.com

$1 = what you got after the /

If you have test.site.com/foo.php , you would have /test/foo.php.
 if you just want test, just forget about the $1.

QSA = query string append,
L = Last.

You should read the url about mod_rewrite in @phihag post.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-_]+).site.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %1/$1 [QSA,L]
```

If you want to link to resources, either use full (`http://site.com/user/static/x.css`) or relative (`static/x.css`) URLs. Absolute URLs (`/user/static/x.css`) will need to be crafted differently when this rule is in effect.

Comment: @Ken , racar Oops, it should be `%1` instead of `%2`. Fixed.

Comment: well, now the 500 error is gone, but it cannot find the page :S

Answer (score 0):

To keep the original address in the address bar you will need a reverse proxy rather than a redirect. Redirecting tells the browser to send a second request to the server with a different address, reverse proxy tells the server to find another page and send it without notifying the browser about it (this is what you want I believe). Reverse proxy is achieved with the [P] flag in mod_rewite

Make sure `mod_rewrite`, `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` are loaded and put the directives

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://site.com/user/$1 [PL]
```

into your virtual host configuration for user.site.com or .htaccess if you do not have root privileges. This will proxy all pages from the subdomain to the main domain folder. If you only want to proxy the index page use `RewriteRule ^/ http://site.com/user` instead.

I assume you are using http and not https. If so, it gets a little more complex...